# Writing unittests for immutability

Tags: java, junit, immutability

I have written couple of classes which are designed to be immutable. I am trying to test them. I can certainly use [MobilityDetector](https://github.com/MutabilityDetector/MutabilityDetector) but I want to write something on my own. Not extensive, something basic.

The idea which I am trying to put in my test cases that on each action, the object reference for the object I performed action would be different than the object returned from the action.

For example, let's say I have designed a class say `Digit` and it has a method called `add`. So the test case I am writing is

```
@Test
public void test_add(){
    Digit zero = Digit.getInstance(); //ignore why i am using getinstance here

    Digit result = zero.add(new Random().nextInt());

    assertNotEqual (zero, result); //there is no equal method overridden in Digit class
}
```

My assumption here is that `assertNotEqual` will test the *reference* of two objects (`zero` and `result`). If both references are different then it means that the operation performed on `zero` object did return a new object rather the old one.

Does this make sense?

Comment: 1. Personally, if your methods are this simple, I might consider not testing them.  A realistic example might help.  2. If `nextInt()` returns 0, might it not be reasonable to return the original object?  I think this test might be prone to intermittent failures.

Comment: @markspace thanks for the input. i may not be able to share original code since its related to an assignment that i am working on. The actual code is about implementing datastructure and their basic operations. 

@StephenC - sure, instead of using equals, i can just `==` operator. 

But question still remains the same. is it right approach to test immutability.

Comment: Don't use randomness in a unit test. There's no value. Use constants.

Answer (score 0):

> My assumption here is that assertNotEqual will test the reference of two objects

Don't assume.  Read the [javadoc](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertNotEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))! It says:

> Asserts that two objects are not equals. If they are, an AssertionError without a message is thrown. If unexpected and actual are null, they are considered equal.

In other words, this is using the standard `Object::equals(Object)` method of testing equality.  That will only use `==` comparison if that is whaat the relevant `equals(Object)` method does under the hood.

---

To answer your question, testing for `zero == result` is neither a necessary or sufficient test for immutability.

- `zero` plus some random integer could be zero
- The fact that `zero` is `==` or not `==` to `result` does not prove that the `zero` object's state has not changed.

In fact, I don't think that there is a valid test for immutability in the general sense.  The immutability property is about what is happening inside the abstraction boundary of your `Digit` class.  If you treat `Digit` as a true black box, you cannot assume that you will be able to detect changes inside the box.

The only valid way to test for (true) immutability is to combine testing with (sure) knowledge of what is happening "inside the box"; i.e. code inspection of your `Digit` class and white-box testing.

Another alternatively, is to define what you mean by "immutability" in terms of certain externally visible attributes of `Digit`; e.g. what `toString()` returns.   (But there are problems with that approach too ...)

Comment: how would you do white box testing in this case?

Comment: I would start by looking at the `Digit` class.

Answer (score 0):

`assertEquals`/`assertNotEquals` test for equality using the `equals` method of the objects. It's similar to `assertTrue(expected.equals(actual))`. If equal is not overridden, it will check the object's references (hashcode), but I wouldn't rely on this as this is likely to break your test if you implement the equals method eventually.

If you want to check, whether the objects are the same (or not) use `assertSame`/`assertNoSame` which test on reference equality, similar to `assertTrue(expected == actual)`.

But to check for immutability is not only checking if any modifying operation returns a new instance, but also checking the original object is still unchanged!

One way to do this is, is to create a reference object (or a clone) of the original object and *additionally* check, that the original object still equals the reference object after calling `add`.

```
@Test
public void test_add(){
    Digit zero = Digit.getInstance();

    Digit goldenMaster = zero.clone(); //if clone is implemented
    //or this
    Digit goldenMaster = Digit.getInstance(); 

    Digit result = zero.add(new Random().nextInt());

    assertNotSame (zero, result); //use check for reference
    assertEquals(goldenMaster, zero); //check the original object is still unmodified
}
```

But this in return requires you properly implement equals.